# How to pass an object's address on the heap from a function using a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to create an object on the heap, then pass back it's address from a calling function, but I can't get it to work!

If this function is called from main, why can't I store the address of the object in a new pointer?

```
Feline newFeline(int height, int weight) {
  Feline *myFeline = new Feline(height, weight);
  return *myFeline;
}

int main()
{
  Feline *f2;
  *f2 = newFeline(10, 100);
  //cout << f2->getHeight() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it I get a bus error: 10. Oh and I do like cats.

Comment: Use a pointer return type `Feline* newFeline(int height, int weight) ` and `return myFeline;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First of all, the newFeline function will return a temporary Feline.  And the method itself has a memory leak (the allocated Feline is not deallocated).  Normally, the temporary will disappear after the statement that called the newFeline function.

Second, you are filling in the memory contents where f2 is currently pointing to.  But f2 is not initialized, so it is pointing to a random memory address.  Copying the temporary Feline into this memory address will crash your application.

To solve it, you need to change newFeline so that it returns the address of the allocated Feline, not a copy of it, like this:

```
Feline *newFeline(int height, int weight) {
   Feline *myFeline = new Feline(height, weight);
   return myFeline;
}
```

Second, let f2 point to the return value of newFeline, not change the contents of f2, like this:

```
Feline *f2;
f2 = newFeline(10, 100);
```

Better is to write it on one line, like this:

```
Feline *f2 = newFeline(10, 100);
```

Or use the C++11 auto keyword:

```
auto f2 = newFeline(10,100);
```

To prevent memory leaks, it's even better to let newFeline return a unique_ptr to Feline, like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Feline> newFeline(int height, int weight) {
   Feline *myFeline = new Feline(height, weight);
   return myFeline;
}
```

That way, f2 (if using auto) will also become a unique_ptr, and when f2 goes out of scope, the allocated Feline will be automatically deleted.

Comment: So many great answers on this thread. The idea of using a unique_ptr, which also deletes f2 when it is out of scope, is really good though. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

Change the signature of your function to return a pointer, and return the pointer by value

```
Feline* newFeline(int height, int weight)
{
  Feline *myFeline = new Feline(height, weight);
  return myFeline;
}
```

As currently written, you return a `Feline` by value, and proceed to immediately leak the `Feline` that you allocated with `new`.

Comment: @TimHUK: It's really painful when questions get changed after they've been answered. It makes everything confusing for anyone who would read this later. Additionally, your changes made your code not even compile, which you still claimed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this ie, return a pointer from your function:

```
Feline* newFeline(int height, int weight)
{
  Feline *myFeline = new Feline(height, weight);
  return myFeline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very fragile. To get it to compile, you could try the following:

```
Feline newFeline(int height, int weight)
{
    Feline *myFeline = new Feline(height, weight);
    return *myFeline;
}

int main()
{
    Feline f2;
    f2 = newFeline(10, 100);
}
```

However this leaks memory and assumes that `Feline` objects can be copied.

In this case I would simply call `Feline`'s constructor directly and not use any pointers or a separate function.

```
int main()
{
    Feline f2(10, 100);
}
```

If you do want to return it from a function, you can use the following if `Feline` supports copying and you are not using the type polymorphically:

```
Feline newFeline(int height, int weight)
{
    Feline myFeline(height, weight);
    return myFeline;
}

int main()
{
    Feline f2 = newFeline(10, 100);
}
```

But if you copy the result of this function into a base class of `Feline`, you will get object slicing.

If this is a problem, then I suggest you use a smart pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<Feline> newFeline(int height, int weight)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Feline> myFeline(new Feline(height, weight));
    return myFeline;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Feline> f2 = newFeline(10, 100);
    f2->do_stuff();
}
```